# Words normalization using RDD

Tags: lucene, apache-spark, rdd

Maybe this question is a little bit strange... But I'll try to ask it.

Everyone, who wrote applications with using Lucene API, seen something like this:

```
public static String removeStopWordsAndGetNorm(String text, String[] stopWords, Normalizer normalizer) throws IOException
{
    TokenStream tokenStream = new ClassicTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_44, new StringReader(text));
    tokenStream = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, tokenStream, StopFilter.makeStopSet(Version.LUCENE_44, stopWords, true));
    tokenStream = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, tokenStream);
    tokenStream = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, tokenStream);
    tokenStream.reset();
    String result = "";
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) 
    {
        CharTermAttribute token = tokenStream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        try
        {
            //normalizer.getNormalForm(...) - stemmer or lemmatizer
            result += normalizer.getNormalForm(token.toString()) + " ";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //if something went wrong
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite words normalization using RDD? 
Maybe someone have an example of this transformation, or can specify web resource about it?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used a similar example for a talk. It shows how to remove the stop words. It has no normalization phase, but if that `normalizer.getNormalForm` comes from a lib that can be reused, it should be easy to integrate.

This code could be a starting point:

```
// source text
val rdd = sc.textFile(...)  
// stop words src
val stopWordsRdd = sc.textFile(...) 
// bring stop words to the driver to broadcast => more efficient than rdd.subtract(stopWordsRdd)
val stopWords = stopWordsRdd.collect.toSet
val stopWordsBroadcast = sc.broadcast(stopWords)
val words = rdd.flatMap(line => line.split("\\W").map(_.toLowerCase))
val cleaned = words.mapPartitions{iterator => 
    val stopWordsSet = stopWordsBroadcast.value
    iterator.filter(elem => !stopWordsSet.contains(elem))
    }
// plug the normalizer function here
val normalized = cleaned.map(normalForm(_))
```

Note: This is from the Spark job point of view.  I'm not familiar with Lucene.

Comment: Thanx Man! I'll try to use it and inform about results!

Comment: Man! I need advice... How do You think - what approach is more effective - take documents and scatter them to nodes, then tokenize and normalize words of each document, or consecutively take each document, tokenize it and normalize words by scatter them to nodes, where each node will have a copy of normalizer function? Thank You!