# K-means clustering by using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, k-means

I would like to do "text clustering" using  k-means and Spark on a massive dataset. As you know, before running the k-means, I have to do pre-processing methods such as TFIDF and NLTK on my big dataset. The following is my code in python :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Cluster a bunch of text documents.
    import re
    import sys

    k = 6
    vocab = {}
    xs = []
    ns=[]
    cat=[]
    filename='2013-01.csv'
    with open(filename, newline='') as f:
        try:
            newsreader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in newsreader:
                ns.append(row[3])
                cat.append(row[4])
        except csv.Error as e:
            sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, newsreader.line_num, e))


    remove_spl_char_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)) # regex to remove special characters
    remove_num = re.compile('[\d]+')
    #nltk.download()
    stop_words=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

    for a in ns:
        x = defaultdict(float)


        a1 = a.strip().lower()
        a2 = remove_spl_char_regex.sub(" ",a1)  # Remove special characters
        a3 = remove_num.sub("", a2)  #Remove numbers
        #Remove stop words
        words = a3.split()
        filter_stop_words = [w for w in words if not w in stop_words]
        stemed = [PorterStemmer().stem_word(w) for w in filter_stop_words]
        ws=sorted(stemed)


        #ws=re.findall(r"\w+", a1)
        for w in ws:
                vocab.setdefault(w, len(vocab))
                x[vocab[w]] += 1
        xs.append(x.items())
```

Can anyone explain to me how can I do the pre-processing step in Spark, before running the k-means.

Comment: See this question for a start point:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944216/words-normalization-using-rdd

Comment: @maasg I am not completely certain if I understand your solution. Actually, I am new in Spark and am going to do these steps : 1- Tokenize and stem the documents 2- create a dictionary out of all the words in the collection of documents and compute TF 3- vectorize document by using TF-IDF

Comment: that solution gives you an sketch of how to do (1) and (2). Note that you don't create a dictionary  in Spark but rather a collection of pairs.

Comment: This command (val stopWordsRdd = sc.textFile(...) ) is creating a rdd from the stop words am I right? if so what should I put in the stop words textFile ? Should I copy these stop words in that .txt file "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
"for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
"no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
"that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
"they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in response to comment by user3789843.

Yes. Each stop word in a separate line without quotes.
Sorry, I do not have permission to comment.